# Что прописать в state вместо null чтобы изначально была открыта первая вкладка?

Tags: reactjs

Есть код который реализует вкладки:
Что прописать в state вместо null чтобы изначально была открыта первая вкладка?

```
class TabContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, content } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="tabcontent">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{content}</p> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: null,
  }

  openTab = e => this.setState({
    active: +e.target.dataset.index,
  });

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { active } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tab">
          {items.map((n, i) => (
            <button
              className={`tablinks ${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
              onClick={this.openTab}
              data-index={i}
            >{n.title}</button>
          ))}
        </div>
        {items[active] && <TabContent {...items[active]} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const items = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content:
      '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content:
      '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Third',
    content:
      '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Вот весь код в песочнице:
https://jsfiddle.net/sxtrvo71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active: 0` поскольку 0 - это индекс первого элемента массива

```js
class TabContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, content } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="tabcontent">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{content}</p> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: 0,
  }

  openTab = e => this.setState({
    active: +e.target.dataset.index,
  });

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { active } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tab">
          {items.map((n, i) => (
            <button
              className={`tablinks ${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
              onClick={this.openTab}
              data-index={i}
            >{n.title}</button>
          ))}
        </div>
        {items[active] && <TabContent {...items[active]} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const items = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content:
      '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content:
      '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Third',
    content:
      '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```